# Are the no-damage achievements necessary to get "Golden God" and "Platinum God"?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

In the base game there are five achievements that require you to complete a "layer" of the basement without taking damage. Are these necessary to get the "Golden God" and the "Platinum God" achievements?

Comment: For Golden God, not necessary. I don't know about Platinum God.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platinum God has apparently been modified and [you *do* have to have all no-damage achievements to unlock that achievement now.](http://new.spring.me/#!/EdmundM/q/340266076149408980) ([See also.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/182229/23))

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements#Platinum_God-jpg) you have to get all items from the original and wrath of the lamb expansion in order to get the "Platinum God" achievement, so no.

The "golden god" achievement is just for collecting every item in the original game so you don't need them for this either.

Comment: The wiki says, for Platinum God: "Get all of the TBOI and WOTL items."

Comment: well...I can't read...

Comment: does that answer your question?