# What do you need for Platinum God?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I have 95/97 secrets and a full collection of 198 items. Click to embiggen:

[image: 95 secrets][image: Collection page 1]
[image: All challenges][image: Collection page 2]

All the achievements and secrets I'm now missing are AFAIK ([and astats.nl confirms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpyVe.png)):

1. Spelunker Boy
2. Mama's Boy
3. Platinum God

But as we know, Spelunker Boy and Mama's Boy are [not required for Platinum God.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73020/are-the-no-damage-achievements-necessary-to-get-golden-god-and-platinum-god)

So... what am I missing? Why do I not have Platinum God?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you *do* now need all secrets [per the developer](http://new.spring.me/#!/EdmundM/q/340266076149408980):

> you also need all secrets unlocked for platinum now

This appears to supersede the answer that you found.